# Geocoder doesn't go on Oreo

Tags: android, google-maps, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-8.1-oreo, geocoder

I have an application that must collect address from a marker on Google Maps API. I tested this code and it works fine on devices that run Android 6.0 :

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        try {
            List<Address> addressList1 = geocoder.getFromLocation(currentLatitude,currentLongitude,1);
            Address addressCurrent = addressList1.get(0);
            full_address = addressCurrent.getAddressLine(0); //Detail address
            country = addressCurrent.getCountryName();
            //locality =  addressCurrent.getLocality(); //sub-district
            admin_area = addressCurrent.getAdminArea(); //City
            sub_admin_area = addressCurrent.getSubAdminArea(); //District
            road_name = addressCurrent.getThoroughfare(); // road
            Toast.makeText(this, full_address, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }catch (IOException e){
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Data", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("error geocoder", e.toString());
        }
```

But when I try to run on Android 8.1 devices it returns an error log:

> E/error geocoder: java.io.IOException: NetCode:-1000,NetRes:{}

I tried to search for it but found no solution.
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As [Gencoder doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder#top_of_page) say: **Use the isPresent() method to determine whether a Geocoder implementation exists.**

so call isPresent() method firstly, and manually check device network status.

If still failed, maybe you need create custom Geocoder implementation, [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47070264/android-geocoder-behaves-different-on-some-devices) is helpful.